# Handle click event in experience site Nav bar menu ( Home menu) when clicking from a LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud, lwc-dom, pubsublwc

I am trying to handle a click event on any of my Experience site menu items from one of my lwc components TO Handle when there are any unsaved changes and a user is navigating away from the page after making any changes. I know we cannot access the elements outside the shadow dom.

Is there any other way to achieve this behavior. Appreciate the help. Thanks.